# How are these two power law fitting glm models different?

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, power-law

I have some data that I thought I'd try fitting with a power law (in R).

```
test2 <- structure(list(Depth = c(69, 73, 148, 365, 452, 965, 100, 100, 
120, 120, 150, 159, 180), Value = c(155.29, 28.09, 23.98, 28.51, 
44.22, 13.52, 19.8, 97.35, 69.1, 99.03, 26.4, 35.08, 37.39)), .Names = c("Depth", 
"Value"), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-13L))
```

I tried fitting two glm to this model. In the first model, I log transformed both the independent variable "Depth" and the dependent variable "Value", and tried to fit these with a linear function.

```
modA <- glm(log10(Value) ~ log10(Depth), data = test2, family = gaussian(link = "identity"))
```

I also tried fitting the same data by not log transforming the independent variable, and instead fitting a log link function.

```
modB <- glm(Value ~ log10(Depth), family = gaussian(link = "log"), data = test2)
```

When I examined values predicted by these functions, they seem to generate somewhat different predictions.

```
testPred <- tibble(
  Depth = c(seq(from = 30, to = 150, by = 0.1),
            seq(from = 101, to = 1000, by = 1)
  )
) 

testPred$ModA <- 10^predict(modA, testPred)
testPred$ModB <- predict(modB, testPred, type = "response")

ggplot() + geom_point(data = test2, aes(x = Value, y = Depth), size = 2) + scale_y_reverse() +
  geom_line(data = testPred, aes(x = ModA, y = Depth), colour = "blue") +
  geom_line(data = testPred, aes(x = ModB, y = Depth), colour = "green")
```

[image: power law fitted data]

I don't understand why these approaches would generate different predicted values. Could somebody explain to me why these yield different results? Furthermore, which model, if either is the correct approach?

Comment: That there is some difference between the curves is not surprising as `modA` assumes Gaussian errors on the log scale (and hence lognormal proportional errors on the scale of the original data) whereas `modB` assumes Gaussian errors on the original scale of the data.

Comment: Thanks @Jarle Tufto, this makes some sense. How might I go about deciding which is more appropriate for fitting this data? Also, is there some way that I could modify modB so that it is equivalent to modA?

Comment: Make some diagnostic plots. If your goal is prediction, cross-validate/validate.